# make another Windows keyboard-shortcuts to open a folder?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, keyboard-shortcuts

How to implement an hot key to open Windows Explorer at a specific folder (ex: C:\foo\fight\vril)?

If is possible, I would like to avoid to install another application but perform it in Windows (XP no Vista nor Seven).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Right-click your desktop
2. Select New->Shortcut
3. If you're in XP: name the shortcut.
   If you're in Vista type `explorer.exe`, click Next and the name the shortcut.
4. Right-click the shortcut and select Properties
5. In the Shortcut tab you should see: `Target: C:\Windows\explorer.exe`
   Add a space and then `/root,<folder you want the shortcut to open to>`.
   e.g. `C:\Windows\explorer.exe /root,c:` will open the Explorer window to the root of C
6. Still in the Shortcut tab, highlight the "Shortcut Key" field and click a key combination (like Control+Shift+E - don't mix it with a shortcut combination that exists already).
7. Click Ok.
   Double-click the shortcut to test it.
   Click your key combination to test it.
8. When you're happy with the shortcut, drag it to the quick lunch bar, or to your start menu

And there you have it. Read more about Explorer command line options [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314853).

Answer (score 3):

create a shortcut to the folder in your startmenu/desktop/quick launch toolbar, then set its shortcut key property.

Comment: startmenu/desktop ?
please help me more